# Selenium how to count and keep track of the number of products

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape product's data when given a keyword/search_term and so far, I have managed to scrape all data from the first to the last page.

However, I wanted to change it in a way that I scrape just the first 100 or 150 products which I'm not sure how to do.

I reckon I need some integer value that keeps track of how many items I am scraping and stop when the integer gets to 100 or 150.

I know that I need to change something on the "for page in range (1, last_page)" but I've tried and ended up getting 100 same results for each of the item which isn't what I'm supposed to do.

```
def main(search_term):
    # RUN MAIN PROGRAM ROUTINE
    chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    
    records = []
    url = get_url(search_term)
    
    driver.get(url)
    last_page = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="a-text-center"]/ul/li)[last()-1]').text) + 1
    
    # NUMBER OF PAGES TO CRAWL
    for page in range(1, last_page):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
        print(page)
        
        for item in results:
            record = extract_record(item)
            if record:
                records.append(record)
                        
    driver.close()

# Run the main function given a keyword
main("make-up")
# leads to https://www.amazon.com/s?k=cosmetics&ref=nb_sb_noss

#main("iphone")
```

How would I go on about changing it so that I can scrape the first 100, 150 or whatever the number I want to scrape?

Comment: @Arundeep Chohan I would still end up scraping until the last page, which is not what I want

Comment: Oh so you wanted to break out the double for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to check if the record length is 100 and then break from the outer for loop.

```
for page in range(1, last_page):
    driver.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
    print(page)
    find=False
    for item in results:
        records.append(item)
        if len(records)==100:
            find=True
            break
    if find:
        break
```

Comment: i was a little confused as you changed some wording in the code but I managed to figure it out! Thanks a lot!!